# Struct of alternative questions

Tags: grammar, questions, grammar-myths

I hope, I will be understood cause I'm beginner in English.
My old (former) teacher of English told me that when I wanna construct an alternative questions with the negative form of the verb that I must to put the negative form near the positive form the verb and separate with "or". Like this

> Has or hasn't encapsulation made it easier to work with complex classes?

but I can't find this case in the Internet, even [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/questions-alternative-questions-is-it-black-or-grey)

Just

> Do you want to go to the cinema or not?

So I even don't know which question I should to ask in google?
Please, can You explain to me?
Can I do this, or not? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence beginning "Has or hasn't..." is grammatical, but it's unusual.
This is a more idiomatic way to include that alternative:

> Has encapsulation made it easier to work with complex classes, or hasn't it?

It's not easy to search for such sentences. They're less common than leaving the "or not" alternative out, because the only meaning added is rhetorical. They could be expressing impatience, or that the question is controversial.  The rhetorical aspect is also why the "or not" or "hasn't it" works better at the end of the sentence.

Your Cambridge dictionary reference mentions that aspect:
"We can also ask alternative questions using *or not?* This is a very direct question and sometimes it can express annoyance or impatience."